# Android Market: How to specify the newly required content ratings?

Tags: android, google-play

I received the email from Android Market announcing the new content rating policy and containing a link to [this page](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188189). So I dutifully prepared an application update and uploaded it into draft status, but where the heck is there a way to specify the ominous content rating? Has anybody found it yet?

Comment: Same here. Couldn't find any UI for ratings...

Comment: I didn't even get the notification. Is there a trick to receiving them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email stated that it would be mandatory starting on November 30th, so I assume by then we will be able to assign content ratings.

Comment: There are two important dates for this initiative: The date when apps can/must have content ratings, and the date when all unrated apps will no longer be visible to users with a filter other than "mature". It would make a lot of sense for the two dates to be sufficiently apart. The email is not clear about what happens on 11/30.

Comment: From my understanding, 11/30 is when developers are able to (and must) assign content ratings. They also say that they'll be "launching the content ratings to end-users starting in a few weeks". I'm assuming this will coincide with the release of Android 2.3 Gingerbread along with a revamped market, and the exact release date for that is still hush hush. But yes, I agree that the dates should ideally be further apart.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you need to check the Market Help Center.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/11/content-rating-for-android-market.html

If the function is not yet available to you, then it might just take a while for them to update the interface.